# An Errno::EACCES error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, errno

I am getting an error on my stating server which says `An Errno::EACCES occurred in items#update`:

```
Permission denied - /var/www/ABC/public/items_images/1
 /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
```

My `staging.rb` file permission is set to www:www, same for the public folder, which is recursively set to www:www.

I am not sure of what is happening. Would anyone have a clue?
Thanks

Comment: try `chmod 777` to your file

Comment: do you use apache? under which user does it run? normally it's www-data. by the way: Not the file executing mkdir needs the permission, but the folder in which you want to create that new folder!

Comment: @user2503775 , which file should I run chmod 777?

Comment: @Dominik Goltermann I use Apache and Passenger. items_images:  drwxrwxr-x  www-data : www-data user permissions. Public folder is using the same user permissions too.

Comment: @Roman can you show us the code that executes the mkdir command? Normally everything should be fine if apache is running as www-data and when that folder is owned by www-data